# http and https application creation in heroku

Tags: node.js, http, heroku, https

I have uploaded node.js application to heroku. I use to create application from heroku site and upload files from command prompt.

While doing so, some application is created as http site and some are created as https.

Eg: http://www.sample1.herokuapp.com and https://www.sample2.herokuapp.com

Why I am getting these and how should I convert http sites to https and how I have to create a https sites always.

Please provide with some suggestion or usefull links. Thanks in advance

Comment: Heroku provides free SSL by default on any `*.herokuapp.com`. Not sure how you received http ...

Comment: Do I have to enable this SSL anywhere in app or in heroku site?? But some site have created as http by default and only few site are created as https.. Did SSL is provided by default only a little before??

Comment: Nope :-) As long as you are using `https://www.sample2.herokuapp.com`. If you want to set up SSL on a custom domain name like `https://www.sample2.com`, then you need to acquire an SSL certificate and configure your DNS servers where you purchased the domain name. Here's a tutorial: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl#add-certificate-and-intermediaries

Comment: No.. I dont want to create a custom domain name.. Just want to convert http site to https site.. Is this possible in heroku node.js?? Eg: From http:// www.sample1.herokuapp.com To https:// www.sample1.herokuapp.com

Comment: What I've been telling you is that Heroku domain names are already SSL when you create a new Heroku app. I have no idea why you are saying you were given a Heroku domain that is not SSL.